# What is the correct name for "complement of modulus" function, $f(n) =m - n\ \mathrm{mod}\ m$?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, arithmetic

What is the name of the function $f$, defined below?

$$f(n) = m - n\bmod m$$

or

$$n\bmod m + f(n) = m $$

If I were to make up a name, I would probably choose "complement modulus," and maybe $\mathrm{dom}$ or $\overline\bmod$ ("$\bmod$" with an overbar) for an abbreviation.

For example, the "$\bmod 4$" of the first eight natural numbers would be $(1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0)$; while the "$\mathrm{dom}\ 4$" of the same would be $(3, 2, 1, 4, 3, 2, 1, 4)$.

Comment: I would call it `round`.

Comment: @conditionalMethod "$\mathrm{round}$", as in "round to the nearest integer?" That's not what this is.

Comment: There are many rounds. When you round you remove the remainder modulo $1$. There are many versions of this (nearest integer, away from zero, ...) depending on how the 'remainder modulo 1' is defined. You can round to the nearest 10th, in which case you remove the remainder modulo $10$. etc. In your case, the only thing changing is the modulo.

Comment: @conditionalMethod see edited version. Sorry for the typos in the original.

Comment: Looks like the additive inverse of $n$ modulo $m$, where the residue representatives are $\{1,2,...,m\}$, instead of the more common $\{0,1,...,m-1\}$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner I think that is close. [Elsewhere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Additive_inverse) I found "modular additive inverse." I suppose that is equivalent to what I am asking, considering `n mod n = 0` .

Comment: This is not a complement _of_ a modulus; it's a complement _relative to_ a modulus.

Comment: @MichaelHardy would you elaborate on the terminology "of" vs "relative to?"

Comment: @conditionalMethod : This is not about making something close to something.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Read the original version of the question.

Comment: @conditionalMethod : ok, I've read the original question. As I said, it's not about making something close to something. If the modulus is $6,$ then the operation is this: $$ \begin{array}{c} 0 \mapsto 0 \\ 1 \mapsto 5 \\ 2 \mapsto4 \\ 3 \mapsto 3 \\ 4\mapsto2 \\ 5 \mapsto 1 \end{array} $$ How is that rounding? $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy Take your time thinking about it. You will get to it. If not keep fixing LaTeX around.

Comment: Related question: [Name for integer "quotient" rounded up (ceiling) instead of down (floor), and the "remainder" we'd subtract?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4661801/name-for-integer-quotient-rounded-up-ceiling-instead-of-down-floor-and-th)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are describing is simply the additive inverse of $n$ modulo $m$, where the residue representatives are $\{1,2,...,m\}$ rather than the more common $\{0,1,...,m-1\}$.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know a name for it, but $f(n)=m\lfloor\frac{n}{m}\rfloor$. Your unlikely to get anything better than @conditionalmethod's suggestion, just as $x\mapsto2\exp\frac{x}{2}$ is unnamed.

Edit: now we've clarified $m-n+m\lfloor\frac{n}{m}\rfloor$ was meant, I don't think that has a specific name either, but I like what you suggested for it.

Comment: I don't think so. Consider very large $n$ and $m = 2$.

Comment: @AnaNimbus It looks based on your example that you really wanted $\color{blue}{m}-n\mod m$, i.e. $m-n+m\lfloor\frac{n}{m}\rfloor$.

Comment: yes. Thank you. edited question to reflect this.